# Shopify pyactiveresource.connection.UnauthorizedAccess when creating a private app on Python

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am working with the [Shopify Python API](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api) and I am creating a private app. As mentioned in the section for [private apps](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api#private-apps), I need to pass the app password as the private access token but when I do that I get the following error.

`pyactiveresource.connection.UnauthorizedAccess`

What should I be passing here for it to work?

My code is as follows

```py
    # Use the client secret as the access token
    access_token = os.getenv("PASSWORD")

    # Set up Shopify session
    session = shopify.Session(shopUrl, GLOBAL_SHOPIFY_API_VERSION, access_token)
    shopify.ShopifyResource.activate_session(session)

    # Get the current shop
    shop = shopify.Shop.current()

    return ORJSONResponse(
        status_code=response_status.HTTP_200_OK,
        content={"shop": shop.to_dict()},
    )
```

Any suggestions?